# Getting older metadata on retrieving file from AWS S3 even if on AWS able to see updated metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

AWS S3 content's metadata has been changed. But while retrieving that content older metadata.I am using boto API. Can anybody help me finding what is going wrong?

I have this code to get distribution object. From it I am creating `signed_url`. I think, here only something is going wrong.

```
url = urlunsplit(('https', CLOUDFRONT_NETLOC, product_path, '', '')) 
distribution = Py33Distribution(connection=conn,config=None, domain_name='', id='', last_modified_time=None, status='')
signed_url = distribution.create_signed_url(url=url, keypair_id=CLOUDFRONT_KEYPAIR_ID,expire_time=expire_time,pri‌​vate_key_file=CLOUDF‌​RONT_PRIVATE_KEY )
```

Comment: Could you please show us your code, and a sample of what problem you are experiencing? For tips on asking a question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hey @JohnRotenstein, I have this code to get distribution object. From it I am creating signed_url. I think, here only something is going wrong.     
url = urlunsplit(('https', CLOUDFRONT_NETLOC, product_path, '', ''))
distribution = Py33Distribution(connection=conn,config=None, domain_name='', id='', last_modified_time=None, status='') 
  signed_url = distribution.create_signed_url(url=url, keypair_id=CLOUDFRONT_KEYPAIR_ID,expire_time=expire_time,private_key_file=CLOUDFRONT_PRIVATE_KEY
                                               )

Comment: It appears that you are wanting to create a Presigned URL for CloudFront content, is that correct? Where is the metadata you mentioned? Also, FYI, these days it is recommended to use [boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) rather than boto.